# Create Item Value Assignment

Tags: 2013, workflow, lookup-column

I have a workflow that that creates an item in a list. Will this works well, I need to set the values for a number of columns which are look ups.

For example, I have a column titled **Process Plan (EOM)** . This column looks  up a value in another list. However in my workflow I need it to set a default value which exists in the list (e.g. **Standard (EOM)**.

[image]

I've tried entering the value of **Standard (EOM)** as that is one of the values in the list and I have tried entering the id of one of the values in the list, but no luck.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Dan

Comment: Can't you create a variable and set the EOM value to that variable?

Comment: I'm just not sure how to do that. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Lookup column you can set the default values through an ID of the item from EOM.  Here are the steps:

**Create a Local Variable (integer type)**

[image]

**Set the default value for the variable**
[image]

**Create the item and assign default value**
[image]